# Nullstellensatz + Zariski Density?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

My algebraic geometry is a little rusty, so sorry if this is really easy. Here is the situation I have:

I have $n+1$ polynomials $p_1(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y)$, $p_2(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y)$, $\dots$ , $p_n(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y)$, and $q(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y)$ in $n+1$ variables with coefficients in an algebraically closed field $k$.

I then know from the context this arose plus the Nullstellensatz that for infinitely many values of $y = \lambda \in k$ that $q(x_1,\dots x_n, \lambda) \in \sqrt{I_\lambda}$ where $$I_\lambda =\langle p_1(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, \lambda), p_2(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, \lambda), \dots , p_n(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, \lambda) \rangle$$ $$\subseteq k[x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n]$$

What I'd like to conclude is that $q(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y) \in \sqrt{I}$ where $$I =\langle p_1(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y), p_2(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y), \dots , p_n(x_1, x_2, \dots x_n, y) \rangle$$ $$\subseteq k[x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n, y]$$

Is this true?

My thought was that if I knew some fixed power $q(x_1,\dots x_n, \lambda)^a$ were in $I_\lambda$ for infinitely many $\lambda$ then probably one could use a Zariski density argument, but a priori I don't think I have control over what power is in $I_\lambda$ for different $\lambda$.

Comment: Take $n=0$, $p(y)=y$ and $q(y)= y-1$. There are infinitely many values for which both $p(\lambda)$ and $q(\lambda)$ are units.

Comment: Yea, ok...  I guess I want $n > 0$ and I want the $p_i$'s and $q$ to have non-zero degree for at least one $x$ variable.

Comment: The basic problem is that say for $y=0$ the polynomials $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ can all vanish identically.  Then having $q$ vanish on the zero loci of the $p_i$ for $y\neq 0$ doesn't say anything about what happens for $y=0$.  For example, take $p = yx$ and $q = x$.  Then for $y\neq 0$, $q$ is in the ideal, but $q(x,y)$ doesn't vanish on $V(xy)$.  For something like this to be true, you would want to know that $I$ is the ideal of the closure of the subvariety given by the union of the subvarieties where $\lambda$ is "good."  This could probably also be phrased in terms of flatness.

Comment: Ahh excellent point, there can be some values of $y$ where the fiber is too big.  I think I can show now that $q(x_1,\dots x_n, \lambda) \in \sqrt{I_\lambda}$ away from finitely many values of $\lambda$, so I guess I still wonder if it holds after localizing away from some finite collection of points but maybe that's the best I could hope for.

Comment: @Nate Yes that sounds reasonable.